# How to determine if BitmapFactory.decodeStream has finished decoding the image from a socket InputStream?

Tags: java, android, sockets, stream, bitmapfactory

I'm developing an Android app that receives an image via `BluetoothSocket` and I'm trying to retrieve its `Bitmap` by using the `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` method, so something like:

```
// Create BluetoothSocket socket and connect
// ...

// Get input stream
InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

// Get image bitmap
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```

What happens is that the application gets stuck on `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()`. To stop the application from hanging forever I have to manually close the socket from the remote device, and only after that the image gets decoded and returned successfully, but this is not a feasible solution for my application since I want the image to be transmitted programmatically. Another thing I tried was to create a separate `Thread` and call `decodeStream()` inside of it, then call `Thread.start()` and then `Thread.join(milliseconds)` with a hard-coded amount of time to wait before killing the thread. This works but I'd like to avoid it for 2 reasons:

- I want the transfer to be as fast as possible, but in this case if the image is smaller than expected the thread takes longer than needed
- If the image is bigger than expected, the thread could finish while the data is still being processed, causing some data loss

I looked at the documentation hoping to find a way to preliminarily set the expected image size before decoding the image, so that the app knows when the data has been received correctly, something like:

```
// Estimate length of expected data (size of image in bytes)
byte[] numOfBytes = new byte[inputStream.available()];
inputStream.read(numOfBytes)

// Set preliminary options
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.setExpectedImageSize(numOfBytes)          // what I would ideally want: set fixed number of bytes 
                                                  // to let the BitmapFactory.decodeStream() method know when
                                                  // the decoding is over

// Get image bitmap
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
```

but such procedure doesn't seem to exist.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

**CODE**

**Server side (C#)**

```
// Create bluetooth socket 
// ...

DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);

// Send image byte array
writer.WriteBytes(imageByteArray);
await writer.StoreAsync();
await writer.FlushAsync();

writer.Dispose();
socket.Dispose();
```

**Client side (Java)**

```
// Create bluetooth socket and connect
// ...

InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

return bmp;
```

Sent:
[image: Sent image]

Received:
[image: Recevied image]

Comment: `inputStream.read(numOfBytes)` You cannot consume the whole stream and after that use BitmapFactory.decodeStream() as the stream is consumed then.

Answer (score 0):

When BitmapFactory.decodeStream() is ready it will close the stream. And hence the socket will be closed too. You say it hangs? Wel... hmmmm. hmmm.

That is why i said you earlier that the server should close the socket after having send the file. [What is causing my image to corrupt during transfer via Bluetooth RFCOMM using FTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70850912/what-is-causing-my-image-to-corrupt-during-transfer-via-bluetooth-rfcomm-using-f)

If you want to keep the connection open after a picture sent/received then you cannot use BitmapFactory.decodeStream(). –

> > hoping to find a way to preliminarily set the expected image size before decoding the image,

Well that is pretty standard. You let the sever first send an integer (four bytes) indicating the lenght/amount of following bytes.

Client first reads that integer and could make a byte array with the right size where it puts the received bytes of the file. You can then use BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(). (or something like that).

Comment: Thank you for the response. If I try to close the socket from the server just after having send the file, the client receives the image just partially. Also, in my case, BitmapFactory.decodeStream() does not close the stream, but it just hangs forever until I close the socket manually, and I don't understand why, is this normal behaviour? I don't want to keep the connection open so decodeStream() would be a good option.

Comment: I also tried to use decodeByteArray (without dividing the data in sub arrays) but sometimes I receive corruped data. I opened an issue about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70850912/what-is-causing-my-image-to-corrupt-during-transfer-via-bluetooth-rfcomm-using-f

Comment: `I don't want to keep the connection open so decodeStream() would be a good option. ` ?? No. That is a bad option. You better use decodeByteArray() then.

Comment: You cannot use decodeByteArray() before first having sent/received the size integer. Please show complete code.

Comment: You said that "If you want to keep the connection open after a picture sent/received then you cannot use BitmapFactory.decodeStream()", but this is not the case, as I actually want the connection to be closed after the image transfer. Sorry if I didn't make it clear.

Comment: When I say "I tried to use decodeByteArray" I mean that I also send the size interger first. The code for the client side is the same I reported in the SO issue you also mentioned (I use decodeByteArray there). While for the server side I now send the data all at once and I avoid using utf8 encoding as you suggested

Comment: Supposing I want to use decodeStream(), when should I close the socket from the server side? Because if I close it immediately after having send the data, the client receives just a portion of the image

Comment: The server should be able to close the socket rigth away. That is what i said. Maybe with your implementation there is no automatic flush(). Try to flush() first.

Comment: Thanks, I was actually missing the flush() in my server app. However, the image is still received partially by the client

Comment: You are not really using decodeStream with those options is it? Please post actual code.

Comment: Sorry i dont know what goes wrong. Is imageByteArray filled correctly?

Comment: Yes, imageByteArray is fine

Answer (score 0):

If the `decodeStream` doesn't complete, that most likely means that the `InputStream` it is trying to read from has blocked.  And that means that it hasn't received the data it expects.

There is another *possible* explanation: the server could be sending a malformed image that is causing the decoder to get stuck on the client side.  One example in Java 5's image decoder ... long since fixed ... was [CVE-2006-6745](https://www.cve.org/CVERecord?id=CVE-2006-6745).  There may be more recent ones.

Apparently, unlike the Java SE image decoder classes, Android's `decodeStream` **does not call `close()`**.  That means that **there isn't any way to tell if the `decodeStream` call has completed apart from checking the value that it returns**.  The [javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory#decodeStream(java.io.InputStream)) states:

> *"If the input stream is null, or cannot be used to decode a bitmap, the function returns null. The stream's position will be where ever it was after the encoded data was read."*

But I think you are really missing the point.  Correct me if I am wrong, but what you are actually trying to do is to stop the client size from blocking the server and vice versa.  The solution to that is to use timers or timeouts.

- On the server side, use a timer to detect that it has taken too long to send the (complete) image file.
- On the client side, use a timer to detect that the `decoderStream` has taken too long.
- In either case, the your code should then be able to call close the stream.  On the client side, the `decoderStream` call should then  return `null`.  (At least, that is what the documentation seems to imply.)

---

Your idea for fixing this was something like the following:

```
byte[] numOfBytes = new byte[inputStream.available()];
inputStream.read(numOfBytes);
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.setExpectedImageSize(numOfBytes);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
```

This approach is fatally flawed.

1. Calling `InputStream.available` on a socket input stream **ONLY** tells you how much data can be read **without blocking**.  Basically, that is the data that has already been received into the kernel TCP/IP buffers on the client side.  It probably won't be the entire image.

   Basically, calling `InputStream.available` is rarely the right thing to do.  (IMO, it would be a good idea if they deprecated it ... though I doubt that they will.)
2. Therefore `inputStream.read(numOfBytes)` won't read the entire image.
3. But then you don't do anything useful with `numOfBytes`.
4. There isn't a way to set an "expected image size" in the `Options`.