# Conversion Bluetooth inputstream to an image, java android app

Tags: java, android, image, bluetooth, inputstream

How to convert bluetooth inputstream to an image in java android app?
Data are devided into chunks. Chunk by chunk is catched in inputstream, but it can't hold more than one chunk. The idea is to put together all chunks (stream by stream) to a byte array and then make a bitmap.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70850912/what-is-causing-my-image-to-corrupt-during-transfer-via-bluetooth-rfcomm-using-f?noredirect=1#comment125255717_70850912

Answer (score 0):

```
    private val mmInStream: InputStream = mmSocket.inputStream
           private val mmOutStream: OutputStream = mmSocket.outputStream
           private val mmBuffer: ByteArray = ByteArray(1024) // mmBuffer store for the stream
    
           override fun run() {
               var numBytes: Int // bytes returned from read()
    
               // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs.
               while (true) {
                   // Read from the InputStream.
                   numBytes = try {
                       mmInStream.read(mmBuffer)
                   } catch (e: IOException) {
                       Log.d(TAG, "Input stream was disconnected", e)
                       break
                   }
    
                   }


// Now the bytes read can be write to a file let's say .png/.jpeg image file.
   fun write(bytes: ByteArray) {
       try {
           mmOutStream.write(bytes)
       } catch (e: IOException) {
           Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when sending data", e)
          
           }
      
       }
      
   }
```